# Block SharePoint Online APIs

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, api

Is it possible to block people from using SharePoint Online APIs like REST, etc even if they have permissions to access a site?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible in SharePoint online.
And I guess in on-prem as well.

By the way, why would you block? It would be an interesting scenario

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The reason for this is governance. At my customer's company they deal with sensitive information and quite strict about what people can do with IT systems. They want make sure users are going through some IT review before building some apps that will access data in SharePoint. It's large organization, so sometimes someone in some department decides to hire a contractor on their own to build something instead of involving company's IT.